# Error Using HTTPS to get the authentication token for Magento2 Rest

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token

I am using Magento2 Rest API with token-based authentication. 
http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
It is working when using HTTP. However it doesnot work with HTTPS.

SSL Certificate is added to the website. I can access the front and admin pages using HTTPS. What is the problem? HTTP is not secure.